# Login en laravel teniendo una llave compuesta

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

tengo una aplicación en laravel 5.1 con llave compuesta, la mayoría de controladores funcionaron bien, el problema es al querer realizar el login no me permite dado que evalua internamente y no permite tener un array como llave primaria ... hay alguna forma de loggearse??
Ya intente con Auth::loginUsingId y Auth::login sin exito

```
class User extends Model implements AuthenticatableContract, AuthorizableContract, CanResetPasswordContract
{
    use Authenticatable, Authorizable, CanResetPassword;

    /**
     * The database table used by the model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $table = 'user';

    public $primaryKey = ['id','masterKey'];

    public $incrementing = false;
```

lo ultimo que intente fue lo siguiente, pero me vota igual un error

```
public function log(Request $request)
{   

    $logged = User::where('email', $request['email'])->first();

    if (Hash::check($request['password'], $logged->password)) {
        Auth::login($logged,true);            
        return Redirect::to('/admin/etc');
    }

    Session::flash('message-error','Datos ingresados incorrectos');
    return Redirect::to('login');

}
```

.

```
Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\Guard::login() must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable, instance of stdClass given
```

Comment: Las claves compuestas no estan directamente soportadas por laravel, echale un vistazo a esto. https://github.com/laravel/framework/issues/5517 ahi puedes encontrar algunas soluciones propuestas

Comment: Puedes probar `Auth::loginUsingId($logged->id);` en vez de `Auth::login($logged,true);`

Comment: lo realice con Sessión, 
P.D. loginUsingId, bota error al pasarle un array, solo permite un entero o string

Answer (score -1):

Creo que estas mezclando cosas.
Dices:

> no permite tener un array como llave primaria

Con:

```
public $primaryKey = ['id','masterKey'];
```

Le éstas indicando al modelo la ID para la tabla, distinto al que laravel usa por defecto, y esto te esta generando el error al cargar la clase, es independiente de que estés haciendo un login, simplemente te falla ahí porque el login intenta usar ese modelo, que esta mal. Arregla lo de la clave primaria.

Comprueba cosas que pudiste pasar por alto, como indicar la clave compuesta al crear la tabla:

```
$table->primary(['id', 'masterKey']);   //Adding composite keys
```